# In C#, SQL connection is printing: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am trying to do run an SQL statement in C#

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
        @"Data Source=loninasd023.xx.xx.com;Initial 
        Catalog=DB.Manager.Data;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

    if (impersonateValidUser("svc_mgr", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT [data_check_info] FROM [DB.Manager.Data].[dbo].[server_package_status]", 
          conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader);
        }

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The impersonation failed.");
        Environment.Exit(100);
    }

}
```

The program prints this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to read [the following example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is almost the same as yours except it is correct. Your only problem is actually in displaying the data ("reading" the reader) , not getting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SqlDataReader.ToString()` method returns it's full-typed name of type. That's why it returns `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`.

*Actually*, this is done by [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because there is no overload called `Console.WriteLine(SqlDataReader)` and that's why it calls [`Console.WriteLine(object)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and inside this method, `object.ToString()` will called probably.

`Read()` method reads your result *row by row*.

You can easily get your values indexed `0` like `reader[0]`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));  // for Int
//OR
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));  // for strings

}
```